# Trying to build a jQuery filter using HTML data attributes

Tags: jquery, filtering, custom-data-attribute

Trying to get and compare the data attribute of the link I click and compare it to anything that it might match in the DOM.
1.) link is clicked (get data-attribute)
2.) take the inner contents of that data-attribute and find anything it might match in the DOM
3.) if there's a match, add class "show" and class "hide" everything else.

I've gotten as far as being able to acquire the contents of the attribute clicked on.

```
$j(filter_cat_link).click(function(){
    var filter_cat_attr = $j(this).attr("data-category-id");
});
```

Filter links:

```
<a data-category-id="breakfast"  href="#">Breakfast</a>    
<a data-tag-id="vegan" href="#">Vegan</a>
```

Filtered content:

```
<div data-category-type="breakfast" data-tag-type="vegan" class="recipe col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">    
<div data-category-type="breakfast" data-tag-type="vegan" class="recipe col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
```

DOM Objects:

```
<div data-category-type="4" data-tag-type="1 5 6" class="recipe col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>    
<div data-category-type="5" data-tag-type="1 5" class="recipe col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"></div>
```

data-category-type= a recipe category such as breakfast(5), dinner(6), etc. 
data-tag-type= a recipe tag like vegan(1), gluten-free(2), etc.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method? You could probably do something like `$('a').filter('[data-category-id='breakfast']")` or something of the like to filter specific data attributes.

Comment: @aug I looked into... Problem is there are lots of numbers that could potentially be matched. 

As you see in the screenshot I took, I can click on all sorts of filters that have their own data-cat-link values; e.g., 1, 2, 3, 4 that have to then be matched to the recipes data-category-type="1 4 7" 

I need a really robust function that can match and compare all potential possibilities. 

Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$j(filter_cat_link).on('click', function(){

    var filter_cat_attr = $(this).data('category-id'),
        $divs = $j('div.recipe'),
        $matches = $divs.filter('[data-category-id="'+ filter_cat_attr + '"]');

    // clear classes
    $divs.removeClass('show hide'); 

    // add show class to matching divs and hide the rest
    $matches.addClass('show');
    $divs.not($matches).addClass('hide');
});
```

Update:

To search and match elements with multiple values:

```
var filter_cat_attr = $(this).data('category-id');
    categories = filter_cat_attr & filter_cat_attr.split(' '),
    $divs = $j('div.recipe');

// categories will be an array of categories
// or undefined if no data attribute is present

var $matchies = $divs.filter(function(){
    var $this = $(this), categoryId = $this.data('category-id');
    return ~categories.indexOf(categoryId); // returns true on matching category
});

// do something with $matchies...
```

Comment: Thanks! It's pretty close... Issue is, when I click the filter links; e.g., 1, 2, 3 any divs that match 1 and 2 will show up, but once I click "3," the first two remove from the DOM.

In short, even if I select a filter that doesn't match, the first two that actually match need to remain in the DOM.

Comment: @JustinMeyers I didn't notice that you had space separated values yesterday, so I've added an example on how to solve that. There is nothing removed from the DOM - it's a matter of changing CSS properties here (`display: none/block`). Let me know if you're able to solve your issue or if you need more help

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, it's still removing all the recipes if just one of the filters doesn't match. It still won't keep the recipes that actually do match; e.g., 

filter links: 1 & 2 match, but I click on 3 (doesn't match anything) ALL the recipes disappear.